# Different UIKeyCommand arrays for different view controllers in Swift

Tags: swift, ipad, keyboard, uikit, uikeycommand

I have a problem with `UIKeyCommand` in Swift. I have two `UIViewVontroller`, `ProjectsViewController` and `ViewController`. I'm opening `ViewController` from `ProjectsViewController` using this code:

```
let editor = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editor")
self.present(editor!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In my `ProjectsViewController` class I have some `UIKeyCommands`:

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]?
{
  if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
  {
    return [
      UIKeyCommand(input: "n", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(projectWizard), discoverabilityTitle: "Create new project"), UIKeyCommand(input: "t", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(toolsAction), discoverabilityTitle: "Open Tools"), UIKeyCommand(input: ",", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(settingsAction), discoverabilityTitle: "Open Settings"), UIKeyCommand(input: "i", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(aboutAction), discoverabilityTitle: "About")
    ]
  }
  else
  {
    return nil
  }
}
```

And in `ViewController` I have another:

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]?
{
  if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
  {
    return [
      UIKeyCommand(input: "n", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(addFileAction), discoverabilityTitle: "New file"), UIKeyCommand(input: "r", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(runProject), discoverabilityTitle: "Build and run"), UIKeyCommand(input: "w", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(closeProject), discoverabilityTitle: "Close window")
    ]
  }
  else
  {
    return nil
  }
}
```

When my app presents `ProjectsViewController`, I've pressed cmd for Discoverability on my iPad, and it presents combinations for `ProjectsViewController`, but after I've opened `ViewController` and press cmd, Discoverability shows both combinations for `ProjectsViewController` and `ViewController`. How can I separate keyboard shortcuts for every class? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: this is exactly the same problem I have. I'm trying to deactivate the previews controller commands like that  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        self.keyCommands?.forEach({
            log.debug($0)
            self.removeKeyCommand($0)
        })
    } even though, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution and maybe its not the best but I can be sure it works properly.

on the first and second views, define kind a factory function that create all commands you need like that

```
viewController1 {

func shortCutKeys() -> [UIKeyCommand] {
        return [
            UIKeyCommand(input: "1", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(keyInput)),
           ...
            UIKeyCommand(input: "\u{8}", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(deleteNumber(_:))),
        ]
    }

}
```

viewController2 {

```
func shortCutKeys() -> [UIKeyCommand] {
        return [
            UIKeyCommand(input: "1", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(keyInput)),
           ...
            UIKeyCommand(input: "\u{8}", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(deleteNumber(_:))),
        ]
    }

}
```

at viewDidAppear do something like that

```
 self.shortCutKeys().forEach({
            self.addKeyCommand($0)
        })
```

at viewDidDisappear

```
self.shortCutKeys().forEach({
            self.removeKeyCommand($0)
        })
```